# How to verify a ISO (9001, 27001, 14001) certification claim?

Tags: business, international

Many company websites are showing that the company is ISO 9001, ISO 27001 and/or ISO 14001 certified.

Is there any way to request, or registrar to check, the company's certificate globally and to validate the certificate's integrity and validity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO certification is performed by independent third-parties; call the certifier who issued the certificate and ask them to confirm its validity.

These third parties are authorised by the [IAF](http://www.iaf.nu).